# Swift custom the scroll indicator width of scrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimage, scrollbar

I am doing an ios app. I need to implement a customize scrollbar with red color and width = 10 for my scrollView. As I tried to set scroll indicator as UIImage so that I can change the color easily but I do not how to set the width of indicator, even though I tried to set UIImage frame size with no luck.Can anyone help me? Thanks

Code for customize scroll indicator color:

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView){
    let verticalIndicator: UIImageView = (scrollView.subviews[(scrollView.subviews.count - 1)] as! UIImageView)
    verticalIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    //        verticalIndicator.layer.borderWidth = 10
    print("scroll")
}
```

Comment: could you please provide some code?

Comment: Please check the above code, thanks

Comment: have someone found a solution for that?

Comment: I am still struggling to find an answer for this one